# Cant update .html.erb file in a Ruby on Rail application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, erb

I'm totally new in RubyonRail field:
i tried to update the html in a view file .html.erb, but after uploading the file via ftp, the changes dont take place even if the file has changed.
It seems to be cached, is there something I miss?
D.

Answer (score 1):

you need to be sure and restart the application; how you do so depends on your hosting situation, but try touching /tmp/restart.txt.  Passenger-based installs (most low-end hosting fits this description) will restart your app when the mod time on that file changes.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, the tmp folder is empty, it has 4 sub folders: session pids chache and socket each one of them empty too.
Is it normal?

Comment: yes, that's normal for a rails app.  if the restart.txt file is missing you can create it with `touch tmp/restart.txt` from the root of your app, or upload it with your FTP client. The contents don't matter, passenger just looks at the modification time.